# Partial Sum to be invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A_1,\cdots,A_m$ be $n\times n$ matrices, satisfying 
$$m>n, A_1+\cdots+A_m=E_n,$$
where $E_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

Show that there exists a subset $P\subset \{1,\cdots,m\}$ with cardinal $\leq n$ such that 
$$\sum_{k\in P}A_k$$
is invertible.

Comment: What is $E_n$? Also, you switch from $P$ to $S$

Comment: I suppose you mean $P\subset \{1,\ldots,m\}$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, I have edited the problem.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Yes...

Comment: Also, do you mean a proper subset? That is, do you mean $P \subsetneq \{1,\dots,m\}$?

Comment: Also, do you have any thoughts on a solution? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Obviously strict subset is meant, since there is no point in asking this complicated a question to somebody that is not even aware of the fact that the identity is invertible.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes. I am sorry for my careless.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I have edited the problem in precision now...Please move the "on hold".

Comment: @xldd it's out of my hands, unfortunately. Your question still needs two more votes.  If it does come off hold, do let me know.

Comment: @xldd I've re-asked the question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/988549/prove-that-there-is-a-subset-with-an-invertible-sum).  Hopefully this will fetch an answer.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom OK, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we have a solution for $n=2$. I don't know how to do for $n>2$. I hope some of these ideas can help.

Let us prove this result by induction on $m$.

First for $m=3$.
Suppose $A_1+A_2+A_3=Id_{2\times 2}$.

We may assume that each $A_i$ has a zero eingenvalue, otherwise one of these $A_i$ is invertible.

Now, if each $A_i$ has eigenvalues $0$ and $1$ then the trace of each $A_i$ is 1 and

$3=trace(A_1)+trace(A_2)+trace(A_3)=tr(Id)=2$, which is a contradiction.

Thus, there is $A_i$ with eingenvalues different from 1, suppose it is $A_1$, then $A_2+A_3=I-A_1$ and $I-A_1$ is invertible and we are done.

Now, assume the result is true for $m=k>3$.

Let $A_1+A_2+\ldots+A_{k+1}=Id_{2\times 2}$. Notice that $A_1+A_2+\ldots+A_{k-1}+B_k=Id$, where $B_k=A_k+A_{k+1}$.

By induction hypothesis, or $A_i+A_j$ is invertible for some $i,j<k$ or $A_i+B_k$ is invertible for some $i<k$.

If the first case occurs we are done. If the second occurs then $C=A_i+A_{k-1}+A_{k}$ is invertible. Thus, $Id=C^{-1}A_i+C^{-1}A_{k-1}+C^{-1}A_{k}$.

By the case $m=3$ we can add two of these three matrices to obtain an invertible matrix and multiplying by $C$, we obtain the result.